# Have to change the default dateformat in datepicker without using Moment npm (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-storybook

Need to Change the Default **Dateformat**  in the  **datepicker**
I can't use the **NPM**

**(*Angular*)**

Needed Formats,
**Dd mm YYYY,
Mm dd yyyy,
LL &
L**

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material let's you customize the date format to display.
With this method, you could use a specified set of date formats everywhere in your application. To achieve this, you need to implement a DataAdapter that will manage the formats. More info can be found here: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats

You can also tryo touse Angulars Date pipe. It can be used to adjust the format of a date and also adjust it to a locale. It can be used in an HTML-template as follows:

```html
<p> {{ dateObject | date }} </p>
```

To use it, you need to import the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` in your `AppModule`. For more info about the different formats have a look at the documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe